Raydium swap to sell 100% of a token only results in 98% actually being sold
I get the raw amount of Tokens in my account with getTokenAccountBalance and pass this directly to Liquidity.computeAmountOut to put it into Liquidity.makeSwapInstructionSimple().
When i check the transaction in solscan, in the instruction data of
#5 - Raydium Liquidity Pool V4: raydium:swap
i clearly see 100% of the token amount listed under maxAmountIn.
However the inner instruction
#5.1 - Token Program: transfer
shows an actual transferred amount of about 98.3% of the total Token amount.
So 1.7% are left in the wallet.
What i want is to sell 100% and have no Tokens left in the wallet.
Does anyone know why this happens and how to possibly achieve this?
If i check transactions from BullX for example, it's always 100%.
EDIT: Here the solscan. 239087 is the raw value, below 0.235084 is the lesser (non-raw) value.

EDIT2: Maybe i should experiment with other SDK-Methods like
makeSwapFixedInInstruction. The name seems to imply that it has to adhere to a fixedIn amount (or i misunderstand it). Anyone used this before and can confirm?
EDIT3: I used partially this code:
async function getTokenBalance(raydiumSwap: RaydiumSwap, mint: string): Promise<number> {
  const userTokenAccounts = await raydiumSwap.getOwnerTokenAccounts();
  const tokenAccount = userTokenAccounts.find(account => 
    account.accountInfo.mint.equals(new PublicKey(mint))
  );
  if (tokenAccount) {
    const balance = await raydiumSwap.connection.getTokenAccountBalance(tokenAccount.pubkey);
    return Number(balance.value.amount) || 0;
  }
  return 0;
}


const { amountOut, minAmountOut } = Liquidity.computeAmountOut({
  poolKeys,
  poolInfo,
  amountIn,
  currencyOut,
  slippage: slippagePercent,
});

const swapTransaction = await Liquidity.makeSwapInstructionSimple({
  connection: this.connection,
  makeTxVersion: useVersionedTransaction ? 0 : 1,
  poolKeys: {
    ...poolKeys,
  },
  userKeys: {
    tokenAccounts: userTokenAccounts,
    owner: this.wallet.publicKey,
  },
  amountIn,
  amountOut: minAmountOut,
  fixedSide: swapSide,
  config: {
    bypassAssociatedCheck: false,
  },
  computeBudgetConfig: {
    units: 300000,
    microLamports: Math.floor(priorityFee * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL),
  },
});


could you also add the script snippet for this.
